# creating a secure registration web page w/o SSL?

Tags: security

Example, I go to the facebook webpage and see that the http URL is not https.  Maybe they are hiding that it is https. I don't see a lock either on the browser.

In any case, how do websites provide secure registration web pages?  I'm looking to create a registration and user login page.

Thanks for your help!

SP

Comment: this is a bug in facebook, not a hidden feature.

Comment: Yes, you should never actually go from secure login to unsecure content. It is a very bad policy, and unsecure.

Comment: lol how can you say the most popular website in the world has bad policy obviously they are doing something right!

Comment: @Mrk Mnl: What does site popularity have to do with the competence of the people who run it? Facebook has demonstrated that they don't do a very good job with respect to user privacy. But that doesn't matter, because [Facebook does in fact have an https login page](https://login.facebook.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You provide secure registration with SSL. If you do a google search for HTTPS or SSL you will find resources. It is a bit of a large topic. How to go about it depends if you are running your own server or have hosting provided to you by a service. EIther way, you will need a certificate for your domain. If you have your own server you will need to do a lot more configuration.

Here is a [link](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/securing-apache-2-server-ssl) about how to go about it with Apache.

Answer (score 1):

1. your **hosting server should provide SSL services**
2. You should purchase a SSL certificate from VeriSign, or generate a one using OpenSSL
3. Apply the SSL certificate to your web server
4. Create youe Login page normal as you do with your scripting language
5. access the page with https://domain.com/page.php